# Install mini.iso to 80 GB PATA drive

Tags: boot, grub2

I booted from the mini.iso and installed all files to the drive. GRUB complains that the system disk is invalid and asks me to remove the floppy. The boot flag for the partition is on. Is PATA no longer supported by GRUB or am I missing something? Do I need a smaller boot partition than the entire drive. By boot partition I mean whatever is mounted on `/boot`?

The system I want to put it on is a PII Deschutes with 256 MB ram, and I set a swap file of 1 GB. I know that the BIOS has found GRUB because the BIOS message is "Operating system not found"

The partitioning is

```
sda             80G
    sda1        79G              /
    sda2        1G               swap
```

Comment: What partition are you talking about? Where are you installing grub to? You may need a small boot partition for an old BIOS, but not for GRUB.

Comment: Bios have found Grub, but Grub complains about the hdd.

Comment: Solved by removing extra HDD, thus HW problem, thus off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that GRUB became confused due to another connected HDD, with a partition marked as bootable without any bootloader on it. I have now disconnected this drive and everything works.

Comment: Please mark it as an answer.